# Unknown error from Facebook App while requesting access token

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone application in which Iam using Facebook SDK from GitHub to post images. Everything works fine if Facebook app is not installed in the iPhone. If Facebook app is installed in iPhone then, while capturing the access token Facebook app sends control back to my app with unknown error.

Is any one facing same issue?

Which is the right approach to get access token? (from Facebook app or through safari or through inline dialog)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue with Android, everything is fine without the app.

The easy but bad looking method is to see the facebook class and modify the authorize method. Dont know how it works on iOS, in Android the method looks if the app is installed, if it is, he send a notification to it. If not, he make some kind of web view. Try to comment the part where the method looks for the Facebook App. It will work only with the web view so it will work =)